# Missing java classes, althouh jar is added. Netbeans 8.2 + jython

Tags: java, python, netbeans-8

I'm trying to run this example (https://github.com/xinwucwp/mhe) on netbeans 8.2 + jython module (ver. 2.7.2). I created a new jython project and added a start.py file with code from demo2.py (from example), here the full file - https://pastebin.com/DqBrDmnN.

As i understand, i have to add path to java classes - *.jar files. [image]

After that, i tried to run it and got the following error - *from edu.mines.jtk.ogl.Gl import *
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/GLArrayData*, although i've already added jogl-all.jar, which includes GLArrayData.class.

```
import sys
 
from java.awt import *
from java.io import *
from java.nio import *
from java.lang import *
from javax.swing import *
 
from edu.mines.jtk.awt import *
from edu.mines.jtk.dsp import *
from edu.mines.jtk.io import *
from edu.mines.jtk.mosaic import *
from edu.mines.jtk.util import *
from edu.mines.jtk.util.ArrayMath import *
from edu.mines.jtk.interp import *
from edu.mines.jtk.ogl.Gl import *
from edu.mines.jtk.sgl import *
```

Ok, if i run program several times, i get another problem - *from edu.mines.jtk.ogl.Gl import *
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/common/nio/PointerBuffer*

But this class is included in gluegen-rt.jar. I have no ideas how to fix it and i'll be very grateful for your answers or explanation how to run this example, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my opinion, problem was in folders' structure of gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar.

Solution: I used pycharm and jython.exe as an interpreter - [image] I created a simple python project with file from question and added java classes from jars to project folder (please, be careful to the folders' structure and save it in the python project folder).